# Instagram basic display API is missing media published with collaborators

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

By calling the official endpoint https://graph.instagram.com/me/media with the correct token I am getting user's published media. However, I am missing media published with collaborators. The point of calling this endpoint is to get user's feed, if we are missing these media then there is no point of calling this endpoint...

Any idea on how to get medias published with collaborators?